# What is the meaning for a system icon color?

Tags: gnome, icons, microphone

After I updated from Ubuntu 23.04 to Ubuntu 23.10, the system icon for microphone is now orange, but I don't know what this color means in this context. I'd like to ask what this color means here, and whether there are other colors (and icons' combination) that I should be aware of. If someone can point me towards a resource where I can read more about it, it'll be a huge help!

[image: Screenshot with the orange microphone icon]

Other (possibly) relevant information:

- GNOME shell version: 45.0
- Session type: Wayland
- I'm not colorblind

Comment: Hi, It is a privacy-indicator. It is themed with style_class name 'privacy-indicator'. you can override the color to your wish with this code `#panel .privacy-indicator {
    color: #ff7800; }`

Comment: Hello, but what does orange mean here? And where can I find information about this "privacy-indicator"? I tried googling it, but found nothing useful.

Comment: the color is just a style, it is by the GNOME or by the OS provider.

Comment: you may go through https://developer.gnome.org/hig/guidelines/ui-styling.html

Comment: It doesn't make sense for the color to be there just for style considering it's different from the other items' colors. It also goes against what is explicitly stated in the provided URL

"When creating custom UI elements, there are a number of accessibility issues to avoid regarding visual styling:
Using color as the only means to distinguish items of information."

Comment: Hi, I think that is why there is a possibility to change the color as per user wish. Good that there is no restriction on it.

Comment: Same problem. I have two Thinkpads, updated both to 23.10 and only one of them has the orange microphone icon.

Answer (score 1):

The microphone is normally white.
The fact that it is orange means that an application is actively using the microphone. Typically things like having Zoom or Skype running would give you an orange microphone.

https://superuser.com/questions/1277720/how-to-check-which-programs-are-currently-using-my-speakers-and-microphone-on-li has some tips on how to check which application is listening.

Comment: Pavucontrol reports no application or stream using my input devices, but the icon is still orange. Ubuntu comes with pipewire by default since 2022, so I'm not sure if pavucontrol is able to check all devices. I was not able to find how to list listening devices using pipewire.